# SQL query for first digits of a numeric field

Tags: sql, db2

I have a NUMERIC(5, 0) field in a IBM db2 database from which I only want the first 4 digit. I haven't been able to achieve what I want with using CAST.

How can I achieve this in SQL without casting as a String and using substring ?

Ex: 13525 --> 1352

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is is always 5 digits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not cast as a string and use substring?

You can also do:

```
select (case when field >= 10000 then floor(field / 10) else field end)
```

This assuming that if the field has `1234`, then you want `1234` rather than `0123`.

EDIT:

You can also use a string by using two calls to `cast()`:

```
select cast(left(cast(field as varchar(5)), 4) as numeric(4, 0))
```

I should also note that in many databases, you can just do:

```
select left(field, 4)
```

and the database will do the appropriate conversions.  I don't have DB2 nearby to check this.

Comment: I know this is possible, but as stated in the question, I would like a solution that does not use substring.

Comment: @Simon This solution does not use substrings.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, I was refering to the first line of the answer. The posted query seems to work fine, but I was wondering if there was a "cleaner" way to do this. If not, I will accept this answer as it does what I need.

Comment: @Simon . . . The cleanest way is to probably use substrings, but you don't seem to want to use that method.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your help Gordon.

Comment: Well, you said in a previous comment that the number is always 5 digits, so the `CASE` isn't really needed for your case

Comment: @GordonLinoff I wanted to avoid casting to a String because I need to insert the result into another table that uses NUMERIC(4,0) data type.

Comment: @GordonLinoff LEFT ! That is exactly what I needed (much cleaner that any other solution imo). Thanks Gordon!

Comment: @simon `LEFT()` would perform an implicit cast from `DECIMAL` to `VARCHAR`, which will then have to be cast back to `DECIMAL(4,0)` as you say. Also, `LEFT()` is most likely just a wrapper for `SUBSTR()`. I'm not sure what your criteria of _cleaner_ are, but I'd prefer the arithmetic approach here.